# How to Fix "unsupported engine" npm install error on Mac that works perfectly on Windows 10?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to install a Next.js app that is working fine on my Windows 10 Pro onto my Monterey 12.6 MacBookAir.

When I run npm install to add the node_modules to the Mac, I get "unsupported engine" error saying that next-auth 4.13.0 requires node ^12.19.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.13.0, but have node v18.6.0 and npm 8.13.2.

First, I think 18.6.0 is > 16.13.0, but anyway, how can I fix this so it will run on my Mac?

Comment: It is, but the app doesn't support node 18. You have to downgrade your version, Or you can change `engine` property in `package.json`